# How to enter conditional statements using Python and kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to kivy. I was writing the following code using python and kivy which is a quite simple one that asks the user for his/her name and hunger level.

```
import kivy #import kivy module
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput  

class human(GridLayout):
    #This is a human class
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(human, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2 
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Enter your name')) 
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False) 
        self.add_widget(self.name)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Enter your hunger level(0-10)'))
        self.hunger = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.hunger)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return human()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Now I would like to have a conditional statement that will check whether the hunger level entered is less than 5 or not. If so, it will print "normal" else it will print "abnormal".**

What should I do?

Comment: You should definitely go through some Python tutorial. If statements and Classes are explained somewhere in the basics. Kivy is just a package you can use with casual (C)Python, it's not some special Python interpreter requiring different syntax.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking for user input in `__init__`.  Create a custom TextInput class that has a method defined to check the input value and with an if else statement print what you want.  Once you've instantiated that, the user can enter to their hearts desire and you can have your method triggered with on_text_validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously can't check for the hunger level immediatly, before the end of the build() method, the user probably didn't even see a window yet, so you have to organise the code for it to check the value after some time, the question is *when*, usually, you want to react to some event, rather than wait a specific amount of time. Kivy offers ways to do either.

You could decide that the user has to validate its input by pressing a button. To do that, you would add.

`self.add_widget(Button(text="ok", on_press=self.check_hunger)`

and add a `check_hunger` method to `human`, which would check the current text in self.hunger.

But you could decide to be more reactive, and instead to react to any validation of the textinput. To achieve this instead, you can just bind check_hunger to the `on_text_validate` event of hunger.

add

`self.hunger.bind(on_text_validate=self.hunger)`

after `self.hunger = TextInput(multiline=False)`

or simply edit this line to read

`self.hunger = TextInput(multiline=False, on_text_validate=self.check_hunger)`

and just for the sake of the example, if you wanted to check the hunger after some definite time instead, you could add at the top of your program:

`from kivy.clock import Clock`

and put 

`Clock.schedule_once(self.check_hunger, 5)`

at the end of your `__init__` method.

Anyway, to achieve what you asked for, the `check_hunger` method would look something like:

`def check_hunger(self, *args):
   if int(self.hunger.text) < 5:
       print("normal")
   else:
       print("abnormal")`

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

After you've instantiated your human class you can access to hunger level by just writing `human_instance.hunger`.

You can try the below code:

```
import kivy #import kivy module
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput  

class human(GridLayout):
    #This is a human class
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(human, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2 
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Enter your name')) 
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False) 
        self.add_widget(self.name)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Enter your hunger level(0-10)'))
        self.hunger = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.hunger)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return human()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app = MyApp()
    my_app.run()

    my_human = my_app.build()

    if my_human.hunger < 5:
        print('Normal')
    else:
        print('Abnormal')
```

I'm not sure if this code will run or not because I don't know if kivy's app's `run` method is blocking or non-blocking. But you can understand the logic from this code.

Comment: Anything after the `run()` will be executed only after the App dies. Put it either into `build()` or somewhere else into the code structure. Also notice that `hunger` is a widget and behaves like that -> `if <object> < 5` just doesn't seem right. You'll need to access `text` property of the widget and that is a string. `"5" < 5`, etc.

Comment: I put the code within the `build()`. But nothing changed. I'm not getting anything printed on screen.

Comment: run() is blocking, until the end of the program, so this won't work.